# Maxima ode2 fuction gives 'not a proper differential equation'

Tags: maxima

To learn how to use Maxima and its syntax, I am trying to solve a simple problem: find f(x) such that (f(x) + f(y))/2 = f((x+y)/2).

One of my attempts involved using `diff` and `ode2`:

```
diff( (f(x)+f(y))/2, x) = 'diff( f((x+y)/2), x);
ode2(%,f,x);
```

This gives the message "not a proper differential equation". How can I avoid this error in Maxima and solve the problem?

Comment: I am pretty sure your equation is wrong, or you did not write correctly in Maxima syntax. Basically `y` and `f(y)` should be treated as constants in this context. And in Maxima you do not write `diff(f(x), x)` you just write `diff(f, x)`.